# Donation options in an windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing Mobile Banking application for Windows phone. Our application has certain menu like "Balance Enquiry", "Mini Statement", "Fund Transfer", "Bill Pay" etc. Apart from these menu we have some exclusive feature like "Donation" and "Cash on Mobile".

**Usage of both the menu**
Donation : The user can donate to any trust or charity.
Cash on Mobile : A user can send money by just using the receiver's mobile number. The receivercan withdraw money from select ATMs.

**The problem is** 
Donation : I know Donation cannot be done in Iphone App. But I came to know that even windows phone doesn't accept this kind of the donation through app.

Cash on Mobile : I came to know that the word "Cash" has some security concern. So it is not allowed in WP application.

Kindly suggest me whether am I right or these transactions are allowed in the WP applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Donation**

You can't directly "donate to any trust or charity" but you can work around this by using [in-app products](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206721(v=vs.105).aspx) (wp8.x only). In-app purchases can be either `durable` (buy once, own forever) or `consumable` (buy as many times as you want).

If it's an option, that you are part of the donation chain from user to charity, then I'd use multiple in-app `consumables` for different charities and donation amounts. User can pay with credit card, paypal, have amount included in their carrier bill or use any other payment method they have available and/or have registered with their Microsoft accounts.

You can create, modify and track all purchases in [Dev Center](http://dev.windows.com/en-us) dashboard.

**Cash on Mobile**

Never heard of such restriction. Maybe it's something new? There's already apps using "cash" in their name and content, e.g. [Cash Track](http://www.windowsphone.com/fi-fi/store/app/cash-track/f849f8c8-120e-4283-aa4b-c8bf792493fd).